# DOM GetElementsByTagName Problem

Tags: javascript, dom, getelementsbytagname

I am just starting out learning JavaScript and I have just reach the DOM section of my course.

I have a page with 10  tags on it and I have created the following JavaScript to tell me how many I have.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var myLinks = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
console.log("We have ", myLinks.length ," many links on the page");
</script>
```

However in the console it reports this:

We have 0 many links on the page

This is not true as there are 10 links, 9 in the navgation section of the website and 1 in the footer.

If someone can tell me what I am doing wrong that would be great.

Thanks

Comment: Put that code at the very bottom of the page (right before `</body>`) and it will work.

Comment: If you follow a typical setup, the script block appears in the `<head>` section of your page. When it is evaluated, there are not yet any `<a>` elements and thus `myLinks` will be an empty array, with a `length` of `0`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to wrap this in an `onload` handler, because at the point of execution, the DOM isn't fully loaded:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.onload = function() {
    var myLinks = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
    console.log("We have ", myLinks.length ," many links on the page");
  };
</script>
```

Comment: Ah yes! I remember now, thanks for reminding me about the way Javascripts loads depending on the position it has in the document. Unless of course you use that window.onload fuction.

Answer (score 2):

Put the script at the end of your document (before you close `</body>`):